# To display a popup for specific time and then redirect to another page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, submit

When I submit the form ,I want to display a jquery dialog(not alert) showing success message for a specific time and then it should redirect to a new page after that time is over.Please don't mark this question as duplicate,I know this question has been answered before but none of them gives me the desired result.
Here is my html code-

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
Name:<input type="name" id="name" />
Age:<input type="age" id="age" />
<input type="submit" name="save" />
</form>
```

Here is my submit.php code-

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql ="INSERT INTO details(`name`) VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["age"]."')";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 /*here i want to display the dialog and then redirect to new page i.e.-header('Location:enter.php')*/
  header('Location:enter.php');
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I have tried `onsubmit=popup();` ,but this does not gives me confirmation that the form has been submitted.

```
function popup(){
    $("#mess").dialog({});
    setTimeout(wait, 3000);   
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone tell me ,why is my question downvoted?

Comment: After four years on StackOverflow, I have given up wondering why so many users are so fast to downvote. There is no *justifiable* reason for this question to have been downvoted. Never give an unjustified downvote a second thought, they are inevitable. In most cases, some community-minded soul comes along and reverses the negativity, and in the end you profit from it, by 3. :)

Comment: yes ,actually i did not found any reason for my question to be down voted..I already researched everything ..Tried my ways to achieve what I wanted and then I posted my question with full and clear explanation..Anyways thanks again @gibberish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started:

```js
delayTime = 2000; //milliseconds
$('form').submit(function() {
  $('#myMessage').fadeIn();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myMessage').fadeOut();
  }, delayTime);
  //Submission continues after timeout
});
```

```css
#myMessage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
#myMsgDlg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myMessage">
  <div id="myMsgDlg">
    <h3>Any HTML at all can be in here</h3>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/100" />
  </div>
  <!-- #myMsgDlg -->
</div>
<!-- #myMessage -->

<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
  Name:
  <input type="name" id="name" />Age:
  <input type="age" id="age" />
  <input type="submit" name="save" />
</form>
```

---

If you wish to display a confirmation message AFTER the form was submitted, your code should look like this:

```js
$('#submitme').click(function() {
  var nam = $('#name').val();
  var age = $('#age').val();
  if (nam == '' || age == '') {
    alert('Please complete all fields');
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'submit.php',
    data: 'nm=' + nam + '&ag=' + age
  }).done(function(d) {
    if (d == 'success') {
      $('#myMessage').fadeIn();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myMessage').fadeOut();
      }, 1500, function() {
        window.location.href = 'enter.php';
      });
    } else {
      alert(d);
    }
  }); //END done function
}); //END submitme.click
```

```css
#myMessage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
#myMsgDlg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myMessage">
  <div id="myMsgDlg">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/150" />
    <h3>Any HTML at all can be in here</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- #myMsgDlg -->
</div>
<!-- #myMessage -->

<div id="myDiv">
  Name:
  <input type="name" id="name" />Age:
  <input type="age" id="age" />
  <input id="submitme" type="button" />
</div>
```

**And your PHP would now be:**

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $sql ="INSERT INTO details(`name`) VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["age"]."')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: And no need to use a jQueryUI `.dialog()` when you can make your own so easily. There is a time/place for jQueryUI dialogs, but so much more power when you roll your own. *Bon chance*

Comment: Run the first code snippet and you'll see how simple it is to make a working dialog. all you really need is: `position:absolute;` and `z-index`, along with `show`  (or `fadeIn)` and `hide/fadeOut`

Comment: yeah ...that's awesome ...I hated jquery dialog box ,but had to use them because i didn't knew that we could create one and that too so easily...